# Needed windows Batch script to calculate cpu utilization, memory utilization and disk usage

Tags: batch-file

Looking for windows batch script or .net code to calculate exact CPU utilization, Memory Utilization and disk usage. At the end we need to load this in some file.

Answer (score 1):

**1.[Perfomance counters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-performance-counters.html)**
You can use performance counters trough [TYPEPERF](http://ss64.com/nt/typeperf.html) or [LOGMAN](http://ss64.com/nt/logman.html) commands:
Disk usage :

```
typeperf "\PhysicalDisk(*)\% Disk Time"
```

CPU (in bat file you should use double %):

```
typeperf "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
```

Network:

```
typeperf "\Network Interface(*)\Current Bandwidth"
```

You can tune the number of samples you want with the **TYPEPERF** switches.Or check the **LOGMAN** command which creates its owns reports - even in binary with some visualized data.As the question is too broad and could not know what you want he data is not parsed.

**2.[WMI(C)](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)**

Disk usage:

```
WMIC  LOGICALDISK GET Name,Size,FreeSpace /format:value
```

this will only show the free space and size. Utilization can be get only through performance counters.

CPU:

```
wmic cpu get loadpercentage /format:value
```

Network:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface get /format:value
```

Both ways can be used with .NET...